# Design a Lock for SQL Server to help relax the conflict between INSERT and SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

SQL Server is SQL Azure, basically it's SQL Server 2008 for normal process.

I have a table, called `TASK`, constantly have new data in (new task), and removed (task complete)

For new data in, I use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT ...`, most of time takes very long, lets say dozen of minutes.

For old data out, I first use `SELECT (WITH NOLOCK)` to get task, `UPDATE` to let other thread know this task already starts to process, then `DELETE` once finished.

Dead lock sometime happens on `SELECT`, most time happens on `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

this is not time critical task, so I can start process the new data once all INSERT finished. Is there any kind of LOCK to ask SELECT not to select it before the INSERT finished? Or any kind of other suggestion to avoid Conflict. I can redesign table if needed.

Comment: SELECT...nolock... by definition cannot establish locks, and so should not have any part in the deadlock. Did you mean the INSERT...SELECT... is part of the deadlock?

Comment: I guess what happened is: UPDATE or DELETE kicked on the row that still in the INSERT process. So, if not SELECT it in first place, then will be no more deadlocks.

Comment: all this should be done in read consistent mode.  so anything that is in the middle of INSERT, but not yet committed, cannot be deleted by another transaction.

Comment: "Dozens of minutes" implies huge tables, awkward processes, and/or poor or absent indexing. Lotsa things could be going on here. We'd need to know a lot more before we could give better than general opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

later the sqlserver2005,resolve lock is easy.
for conflict 
1.you can use the service broker.
2.use the isolution level.

dbcc useroptions ,at last row ,you can see the deflaut isolution level is read_committed,this is the session level.
we can change the level to read_committed_snapshot for conflict,in sqlserver, not realy row lock like oracle.but we can use this method implement.

ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;

open this feature,must in single user schame.

and you can test it.
for session A ,session B.

A:update table1 set name = 'new' with(Xlock) where id = 1
B:you still update other row and select all the data from table.

my english is not very good,but for lock ,i know.

in sqlserver,for function ,there are three locks.
1.optimistic lock ,use the timestamp(rowversion) control.
2.pessimism lock ,force lock when use the date.use Ulock,Xlock and so on.
3.virtual lock,use the proc getapplock().

if you need lock schame in system architecture,please me email : mjjjj2001@163.com

Answer (score 1):

Consider using service broker if this is a processing queue.

There are a number of considerations that affect performance and locking. I surmise that the data is being updated and deleted in a separate session. Which transaction isolation level is in use for the insert session and the delete session.

Has the insert session and all transactions committed and closed when the delete session runs? Are there multiple delete sessions running concurrently? It is very important to have an index on the columns you are using to identify a task for the SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, especially if you move to a higher isolation level such as REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZED.

All of these issues could be solved by moving to Service Broker if it is appropriate.

Comment: SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE are concurrently. Only INSERT is singleton. Is there a way to lock the row and mark it cannot be select, then unlock(unmark) it after INSERT. There are index(s) there, I know concurrently is the root cause of the problem but for performance, I have to use concurrently process. I think my question can be simply ask: Is there a way to make the row unselectable before insert complete?

Comment: It defaults to being non-selectable. But by using `with(nolock)` you override that. Why are you using nolock if you want the row locked?